# What kind of significance test would this be?

Tags: statistics

Do teenage girls want to get married earlier in life than teenage boys? I was thinking a two sample z-test but I am now unsure.

Comment: How are you measuring "want to"?

Comment: Also, are you trying to determine (a) what age they first decide they want to be married,(b) the proportion of teenage boys vs girls that are actively trying to get married (or would if given the chance) or (c) that teenage girls would like to be married at an earlier age (say, by age 25) than teenage boys (who may be aiming for, say, 30 years old)?

Answer (score 0):

No matter whether you are measuring reality or aspiration, I think
this is going to be a two-sample t test. You certainly will
have two distinct samples of randomly chosen teenagers. (If feasible, it
may be a good idea to specify specific age ranges that are not
too wide and apply the restriction to both samples.)
It is the best use of resources for the two sample sizes to be approximately equal. That will give you maximum 'power' (ability
to detect a difference) for a given total sample size.

I can't imagine circumstances in which you would know the variances
of either the girl or boy population, so you will have four
estimates: two sample means and two sample variances.
You can use a z-test only if population variances are known
(rarely the case in practice).

I suggest you use a Welch (separate-variances) t test, because
one or the other of the populations may be considerably more
variable. (If this difference is really large, that would
be another part of your story.)